# How to select numeric value from nvarchar column in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table like

```
Create table Producttbl ( sno nvarchar(100),sname nvarchar(200),price nvarchar(100))
```

Values are

```
sno    sname price
1       aaa   1.50
2       ccc   5.30 
abc     xxx   abc
3       dsd   kkk 
nn      dss   5.1
```

Price column is `nvarchar` it accept all kind of data like string or numeric.

From that table, I want to select results like this:

```
   sno        sname  price
    1           aaa   1.50
    2           ccc   5.30
```

Please help me.

Comment: If you have sno 1a you get 1 or you exclude it from the result set?

Comment: you may want to use ISNUMERIC function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Have you considered that you should not have nonnumeric values in a price field. Perhaps your design needs revisiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presumably want `sno` values which consist of digits and only digits (otherwise, you need to specify which "numeric" types you wish to accept):

```
select * from ProductTbl where sno not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

We use a double negative check, to exclude `sno` values which contain a non-digit character.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the isnumeric function?

```
SELECT sno,sname
FROM ProductTbl
WHERE ISNUMERIC(sno)=1
```

You should read up on the [isnumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) documentation to be sure that it returns the results you expect.  (see comments below).

Comment: `ISNUMERIC()` is frequently the *wrong* function, since it answers a question that no-one has ever asked. I've never found anyone who wants to treat all of the following strings as "numeric": `'$'`,`'£'`,`'1d6'`,`'1,0.0,5'`, etc...

Comment: Noted, the OP will need to take this into consideration.  Thanks for the addition.